# Change Explorer Tab "Rename File" Keymap

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

In the Explorer tab in Rider my current keymap to change a file name is `Shift`+`F6`.

[image]

In most other systems I use, "Rename File" is `F2`. I've had a look in **Settings** > **Keymap** but haven't managed to find the correct value. Am I able to change this Keymapping?

Comment: You should be able to. Look for `Refactor | Rename...`. **P.S.** The Keymap Settings screen has the "Find Actions by Shortcut" button -- try it. Or just use the search field there to look by the action name. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Settings_Keymap.html#7d652e34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Success! The correct keymapping is **Main Menu** > **Refactor** > **Rename...** `F2` now works!

[image]

Thanks [LazyOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/783119/lazyone) :)